# Why does openCV's convertto function not work?

Tags: c++, opencv, alpha-transparency

I have an image which has 4 channels and is in `4 * UINT8` format.

I am trying to convert it to 3 channel float and I am using this code:

```
images.convertTo(images,CV_32FC3,1/255.0);
```

After the conversion, the image is in a float format but still has 4 channels. How can I get rid of 4th (alpha) channel in OpenCV?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As @AldurDisciple said, [`Mat::convertTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto) is intended to be used for changing the data type of a `Mat`, not for changing the number of channels.

To work out, you should split it into two steps:

```
cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGRA2BGR);       // 1. change the number of channels
image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC3, 1/255.0); // 2. change type to float and scale
```

Comment: Hello sir, What does `1/255.0` ? it is useful for which thing ?

Comment: @Kabyle `1/255.0` here is the scale factor, which will convert values `[0, 255]` to `[0, 1]`. See [`Mat::convertTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto)'s doc for details.

Answer (score 2):

The function `convertTo` is intended to be used to change the data type of a `Mat`, exclusively. As mentionned in the documentation ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto)), the number of channels of the output image is always the same as the input image.

If you want to change the datatype *and* reduce the number of channels, you should use a combination of `split`, `merge`, and `convertTo`:

```
cv::Mat img_8UC4;

cv::Mat chans[4];
cv::split(img_8UC4,chans);

cv::Mat img_8UC3;
cv::merge(chans,3,img_8UC3);

cv::Mat img_32FC3;
img_8UC3.convertTo(img_32FC3);
```

Another approach may be to recode the algorithm yourself, which is quite easy and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's [cvtColor function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) allows you to convert the type and number of channels of a Mat.

```
void cvtColor(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 )
```

So something like this would convert a colored 4 channel to a colored 3 channel:

`cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGRA2BGR, 3)`;

Or it is probably more efficient to use the [mixChannels function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels), if you check the documentation its example shows how to split a channel out.

Then if you really want to change it to a specific type:

```
image.convertTo(image,CV_32F);
```