# Why does setTo not work (assertion failed)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am just learning OpenCV and, since I have some experience with Matlab's logical indexing, I was really interested to see the matrix method setTo. My initial attempt doesn't work though, and I can't work out why, so I'd be very grateful for your help!

I have a Mat containing image data, and want to set all values greater than 10 to zero. So, I did:

```
Mat not_relevant = abs(difference - frame2) > 10;

difference = difference.setTo(0, not_relevant);
```

This however gives me:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mask.empty() || mask.type() == CV_8U) in
cv::Mat::setTo, file 
C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\copy.cpp, line 347
```

I have tried converting not_relevant, difference and frame2 before doing this using, e.g.:

```
frame2.convertTo(frame2, CV_8UC1);
```

but that did not fix the error, so I'm not sure what else I could try. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear.type of your mask image should be `CV_8U`.

so you need to convert `not_relevent` to grayscale.

```
Mat not_relevant = abs(difference - frame2) > 10;
cv::cvtColor(not_relevant, not_relevant, CV_BGR2GRAY);
difference = difference.setTo(0, not_relevant);
```

**Why convertTo does not work here ?**

`CV_8U`(or `CV_8UC1`) is type of  image with **one** channel of uchar values.

`convertTo` can not change number of channels in image.

So converting image with more than one channel to `CV_8U` using `convertTo` does not work .
check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174002/why-convertto-in-opencv-doesnt-work) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thank you omid, it works! Thank you also for pointing out my error -- I had indeed not realised that convertTo did not work here.